# Limit of decreasing sequence of closed (under logical consequence) theories.

Tags: logic

Let $T_1 \supsetneq T_2 \supsetneq T_3 \supsetneq \ldots$ be a strictly decreasing sequence of closed (under logical consequence) theories, where closed means that for any statement $\phi:T_i\vdash \phi\rightarrow \phi\in T_i$.

From $T_2, T_3, \ldots$ onward the theories must be consistent (else they could not be decreasing in size) and not finitely axiomatizable (else we would at some point arrive at a non-decreasing recurring sequence of the (almost empty) theory of tautologies). Is it possible that the limit $\bigcap_i T_i$ is finitely axiomatizable?

Also, this seems similar to the problem concerning the emptiness of a limit of a descending sequence of (topologically) closed infinite sets $A_1\supsetneq A_2\supsetneq \ldots$. This limit $\bigcap_i A_i$ can not be empty if an $A_k$ is bounded. Do you know of any similar topological interpretation of the 'boundedness' of theories?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the language with one constant $0$, an unary function $S$ and an unary predicate $P$, and let $T_n$ be the set $\{P(\underbrace{SS\cdots SSS}_{m\text{ times}} 0)\mid m \ge n \}$ plus all its consequences.

Then the sequence is clearly strictly decreasing, <s>and its limit is the set of logically valid formulas, which is finitely axiomatized (namely, by no axioms at all).</s>

*Whoops, this is not true. The limit also contains all formulas of the form $\exists x.P(SS\cdots SSx)$.* I'm not immediately sure whether this can be fixed, at least not while sticking to a finite language.

---

Also, just because one of the $T_n$ is finitely axiomatizable doesn't mean the sequence can't be infinite. In the above example, we can prepend the theory with the single axiom $\forall x.P(x)$, which is larger than $T_1$, but is nevertheless followed by an infinitely decreasing sequence of theories.